# There alawys has complile error when compile the latest kernel in ubuntu,as follow

Tags: linux, build

LD      arch/x86/realmode/rm/realmode.elf
arch/x86/realmode/rm/header.o: In function `real_mode_header':
(.header+0x8): undefined reference to`pa_trampoline_start'
arch/x86/realmode/rm/header.o: In function `real_mode_header':
(.header+0xc): undefined reference to`pa_trampoline_status'
arch/x86/realmode/rm/header.o: In function `real_mode_header':
(.header+0x10): undefined reference to`pa_trampoline_header'
arch/x86/realmode/rm/header.o: In function `real_mode_header':
(.header+0x14): undefined reference to`pa_trampoline_pgd'
arch/x86/realmode/rm/header.o: In function `real_mode_header':
(.header+0x18): undefined reference to`pa_wakeup_start'
arch/x86/realmode/rm/header.o: In function `real_mode_header':
(.header+0x1c): undefined reference to`pa_wakeup_header'
arch/x86/realmode/rm/header.o: In function `real_mode_header':
(.header+0x20): undefined reference to`pa_machine_real_restart_asm'
arch/x86/realmode/rm/trampoline_64.o: In function `trampoline_start':
/home/xhyang/src/linux/arch/x86/realmode/rm/trampoline_64.S:77: undefined reference to`pa_startup_32'
arch/x86/realmode/rm/trampoline_64.o: In function `startup_32':
/home/xhyang/src/linux/arch/x86/realmode/rm/trampoline_64.S:95: undefined reference to`pa_tr_cr4'
/home/xhyang/src/linux/arch/x86/realmode/rm/trampoline_64.S:99: undefined reference to `pa_trampoline_pgd'
/home/xhyang/src/linux/arch/x86/realmode/rm/trampoline_64.S:103: undefined reference to`pa_tr_efer'
/home/xhyang/src/linux/arch/x86/realmode/rm/trampoline_64.S:104: undefined reference to `pa_tr_efer'
/home/xhyang/src/linux/arch/x86/realmode/rm/trampoline_64.S:118: undefined reference to`pa_startup_64'
arch/x86/realmode/rm/trampoline_64.o: In function `tr_gdt':
(.rodata+0x2): undefined reference to`pa_tr_gdt'
arch/x86/realmode/rm/reboot.o: In function `machine_real_restart_asm':
/home/xhyang/src/linux/arch/x86/realmode/rm/reboot.S:27: undefined reference to`pa_tr_gdt'
/home/xhyang/src/linux/arch/x86/realmode/rm/reboot.S:33: undefined reference to `pa_machine_real_restart_paging_off'
arch/x86/realmode/rm/reboot.o: In function`machine_real_restart_paging_off':
/home/xhyang/src/linux/arch/x86/realmode/rm/reboot.S:46: undefined reference to `pa_machine_real_restart_idt'
/home/xhyang/src/linux/arch/x86/realmode/rm/reboot.S:53: undefined reference to`pa_machine_real_restart_gdt'
arch/x86/realmode/rm/reboot.o: In function `machine_real_restart_gdt':
(.rodata+0x12): undefined reference to`pa_machine_real_restart_gdt'
arch/x86/realmode/rm/wakeup_asm.o: In function `wakeup_gdt':
(.rodata+0x2): undefined reference to`pa_wakeup_gdt'
make[3]: *** [arch/x86/realmode/rm/realmode.elf] Error 1
make[2]: *** [arch/x86/realmode/rm/realmode.bin] Error 2

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow; please format better your post; use the code formatting features allowed by the Markdown editor when writing your post. Don't give a long title containing your whole explanation with nothing more in the body of your post. It is currently very uneasy to understand your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason.
nm tool is not gnu version.

Comment: Do you remember how you solved this? Did you just upgrade nm-tool? I do not even have that installed... I am getting similar errors.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this issue.

I did find a fix. My issue was with: `sed` flags. Specifically, the "-r" in the sed params from the Makefile.

After installing GNU bintools and gsed and then changing the Makefile for the realtime linking to use `gsed` instead of `sed` resolved this issue.

Hope that helps.

~m